# BizTalk project template in Visual Studio 2019 give UpdateVersionTask error

Tags: visual-studio, biztalk, biztalk-2020

I have a working VS2019, I added the Extensions "BizTalk ESB Toolkit Initerary Designer" and "BizTalk Server" via "Manage Extensions" in VS2019

I have restarted VS and also my computer
I do not have BizTalk server 2020 installed on my computer
I do run VS2020 as admin

I can now add a BizTalk projects via "Add a new project" because there is a template named "BizTalk Server Application Project"

When I do this, I get a new BT project
But when I try to add new items, all I get is the "BizTalkServerInventory" option, no other items like schemas or orchestrations
In the New

[image: New BizTalk ESB exist as one option...]

Also, when I try to build I get the following error:

> *Error MSB4018 The "UpdateVersionTask" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. Det går inte att hitta filen.
>   File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.ALM.JsonSchema.UpdateVersionTask.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()*

When I try to add Newtonsoft.Json I get
"Operation failed, The project ProjectName is unsuported"
And after this the "Manage NuGet Packages" i grey...

Comment: Install VS2019 Enterprise instead on a server with BizTalk installed. Noticed that problem project was of type "BizTalk Server Application Project"
But in the Enterprise version was also a project type of "BizTalk Server Project" and this one worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have BizTalk (usually Developer edition) installed on the machine where you have Visual Studio, otherwise the DLLs that are needed for BizTalk solutions will not be there.  And as per you question you also need to install the BizTalk extensions from the Visual Studio Market.

You can get away without configuring BizTalk in a Development environment, but usually it is more practical to also have it configured, so you can deploy locally using Visual Studio and quickly test changes.  Otherwise you would have to have some sort build Server (that usually again requires BizTalk installed) or DevOps pipeline to compile and deploy to a BizTalk Server.